# node:events:505 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 4000;

Tags: node.js, express

node:events:505
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 4000;
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1363:21)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1428:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1527:5)
at Function.listen (D:\REACT JS\E-COMMERCE\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
at Object. (D:\REACT JS\E-COMMERCE\backend\server.js:10:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1407:8)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
errno: -4092,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '4000;',
port: -1
}

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission issue, you can just write sudo as a prefix before your command if you are using linux/Mac